# Appium:conflicts occur in Appium::TouchAction(ruby) when applying multi-threading?

Tags: android, ruby, multithreading, appium

I am running parllel tests on multi android devices using multithreading.The code works fine without multithreading.I think there're some synchronization issues related to Appium:TouchAction.

Here's my code:

```
    require 'thread'
    require 'appium_lib'
    TARGET_APP_ACTIVITY = 'something'
    TARGET_APP_PACKAGE = 'mlab.android.speedvideo.pro' 
    include Appium::Common
    def start_app(device_id,port_num)
        caps_config={ platformName: 'Android', appActivity: TARGET_APP_ACTIVITY, 
        deviceName: '', udid: device_id, appPackage:   TARGET_APP_PACKAGE,newCommandTimeout: 3600}

        appium_lib_config={ port: port_num}

        opts={caps:caps_config,appium_lib:appium_lib_config}
        orig= Appium::Driver.new(opts)
        return orig
    end

    def test(device1,device2)
        cmd1  = "start appium -p 4000 -bp 4001 -U " + device1
        cmd2  = "start appium -p 4002 -bp 4003 -U " + device2
        system(cmd1)
        system(cmd2)
        sleep 20

        threads = []
        threads << Thread.new {
            orig = start_app(device1,4000)
            dr = orig.start_driver
            dr.find_element(id:'something').click
            dr.find_element(id:'something').click
            dest_elem =  dr.find_element(id:'something')
            src_elem = dr.find_element(id:'something')
            Appium::TouchAction.new.press(element: src_elem).move_to(element:dest_elem).perform
            src_elem = dr.find_element(id:'something')
            Appium::TouchAction.new.press(element: src_elem).move_to(element:dest_elem).perform
            src_elem = dr.find_element(id:'something')
            Appium::TouchAction.new.press(element: src_elem).move_to(element:dest_elem).perform

            orig.driver_quit
        }

        threads << Thread.new {
            orig = start_app(device2,4002)
            dr = orig.start_driver
            dr.find_element(id:'something').click
            dr.find_element(id:'something').click
            dest_elem = dr.find_element(id:'something')
            src_elem = dr.find_element(id:'something')
            wait {Appium::TouchAction.new.press(element: src_elem).move_to(element:dest_elem).perform}
            src_elem = dr.find_element(id:'something')
            wait {Appium::TouchAction.new.press(element: src_elem).move_to(element:dest_elem).perform}
            src_elem = dr.find_element(id:'something')
            wait {Appium::TouchAction.new.press(element: src_elem).move_to(element:dest_elem).perform}

            orig.driver_quit
       }

        threads.each { |t|
            t.join
        }
    end 
    if __FILE__ == $0
        test(ARGV[0],ARGV[1])
    end
```

If I only keep one thread,touch actions perform perfectly.How can I synchronize operations of Appium::TouchAction?

Answer (score 0):

I answred you as if you are using java with Appium, because i have not used Ruby before :
A reference for you : (hope that help)
http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/11/pefrorm-multitouch-action-using-appium.html

```
 // Create object of MultiTouchAction class.
  MultiTouchAction maction = new MultiTouchAction((MobileDriver) driver);

  // Set touch action1 on given X Y Coordinates of screen.
  TouchAction action1 = new TouchAction((MobileDriver) driver).longPress(x1, y1).waitAction(1500);
  // Set touch action2 on given X Y Coordinates of screen.
  TouchAction action2 = new TouchAction((MobileDriver) driver).longPress(x2, y2).waitAction(1500);
  // Set touch action3 on given X Y Coordinates of screen.
  TouchAction action3 = new TouchAction((MobileDriver) driver).longPress(x3, y3).waitAction(1500);
  // Set touch action4 on given X Y Coordinates of screen.
  TouchAction action4 = new TouchAction((MobileDriver) driver).longPress(x4, y4).waitAction(1500);
  // Set touch action5 on given X Y Coordinates of screen.
  TouchAction action5 = new TouchAction((MobileDriver) driver).longPress(x5, y5).waitAction(1500);

  // Generate multi touch action chain using different actions and perform It.
  maction.add(action1).add(action2).add(action3).add(action4).add(action5).perform();
```